# R: is it possible to read/process flat file in R

Tags: r

I just want to use R for scripting and having problem with using those syntax to load flat test1.txt which I created on W machine in text editor.
Later I plan to replace some string in it and write out.

Search all R  option and most promising  still produces errors
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 6 elements etc
or
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:/R/X/xxx1.SQL'

```
read.table("C:/R/X/xxx1.SQL")
```

Is it doable in R?  I don't care about any columns structures, it's free text file.

Thanks
Mario

Comment: Please show us at least the header of the file.

Comment: What about just a `readLines()` if you don't care about columns

Answer (score 2):

You should use `?readChar` and `?writeChar`, as you want the whole content in the same character vector. 
Each function has his purpose. `?readLines` to iterate over lines, `?read.table` to parse tabulated files.

```
file.content <- readChar(file.name, file.info(file.name)$size)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
fileAsChar <- paste(readLines("C:/R/X/xxx1.SQL"), collapse = "\n")
```